# Who ordered the execution in Extremis?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Doctor Who* S10E6 "Extremis", our favourite Time Lord<sup>*</sup> was going to be executed. But after viewing it more than once, and after the awesomeness of the whole scene has worn off a bit, I am left with the question: wait a minute, who ordered this execution?

The other Time Lords? Never! They don't exist! Not here, not now at least.

Who then? Who has the authority? Was it ever alluded to?

<sup>*</sup> Or, depending on how much of a perv you are, maybe your second or third favourite.

Comment: The Shadow Proclamation maybe. They seem to have some authority in law enforcement. They are the ones who license the Time Lords to time travel.

Comment: @Bellerophon the shadow proclamation do nothing of the sort.

Comment: @doctortwo There is an episode which shows a plaque on the TARDIS console which says something like 'licensed by Shadow Proclamation'.

Comment: Since before Capaldi's first appearance, the Time Lords and Gallifrey have been right back where they belong -- The Day of the Doctor "fixed" the destruction of Gallifrey before it could occur.

Comment: @Bellerophon as the timelords are the oldest race is the universe and invented time travel, you're reading it wrong.

Comment: I guess I'm a perv: Missy just isn't my type, at all.

Comment: @Martha I didn't say which way the perviness should work. Maybe I meant it the other way around! PS Missy isn't my type either.

Comment: Eh? Other way around what? The Doctor wasn't being executed, he was the executioner.

Comment: @Martha Sorry, I thought you were referring to if Missy was my favourite Time Lord or not. Anyway, I only used that particular wording in my question to avoid spoiler tags, not to hide the fact that I didn't know who was going to be executed..

Answer (score 3):

We don't (yet) know.

I don't recall any in-universe hint as to who might have ordered the execution, though of course the list of candidates would be large.

It may be revealed in later episodes of the series that haven't yet aired, or (given Stephen Moffat's talent for raising intriguing questions and then forgetting all about them) it could be left unanswered forever.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. Please make sure you've read [How to write a good answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Voronwë, just so you know, typing `[tour]` gives you [tour] and typing `[edit]` gives you and [edit] link.